# Linking two TableViews through a TabBar

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode4, uitabbarcontroller, xcode-storyboard

I've got 2 views, the `AlllocationsViewController` and the `LoactionsViewController` which are linked to each other.

That's how it looks in storyboard:

[image]

Each cell of the `AlllocationsViewController` links to the `LocationsViewController` and sends it some data to view in a tableView: `AlllocationsViewController.m`

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{ 
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    LocationsViewController *locationsViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LocationsViewController"];

    //Will send the data from the cell to the next view into 'locationlink', which is set as property in LocationsViewController.h to retrieve the data
    locationsViewController.locationlink = cell.detailTextLabel.text;   

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:locationsViewController animated:YES];

}
```

Now I want to put a TabBar through those views:

[image]

After inserting data, If I leave the code below like that, the TableCell will send the user to the TableView (LocationsViewController), but without showing the TabBar. 
What do I have to change in the code below so it shows me the TabBar too? Do I have to link to the TabBar instead of the locationsViewController now? Or do I have to set the TabBar in the LocationsViewController? 
Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is a little late, but i think i can help you.

I prefer to use PrepareForSegue, but in your case you can use something like this...

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
     UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    ClassTabBar *TabBarController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TabBarClientes"];
    Locations *locationViewController = [TabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0]; // you can use the index you need
    locationViewController.locationlink= cell.detailTextLabel.text;  
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:TabBarController animated:YES];
}
```

Tell me if I can help you in something else

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer, even it's a little bit late - it gives me a good input on how it coul probably work. I'll read through it, thanks :)

Comment: If my answer help you, it would be nice if you mark it as the right answer.